# Filesystem got corrupted overnight

Tags: ext4, data-recovery

OS: xUbuntu 18.04 LTS.
I have my OS installed on 256GB SSD:
/boot on ext2
/ on ext4 (encrypted)
That works fine.

I have installed the second 1TB HDD recently for storage and backup.
Model: WDC WD1002FAEX-00Y9A0
/data on ext4 (unencrypted) - single partition on the whole drive

Last night I left my computer running overnight copying around 200GB file by mounting a directory from the HDD on the remote machine using `sshfs` and copied a disk image using:

```
user@remote$ sshfs user@pc:/data/storage backup
user@remote$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress conv=sync,noerror | dd of=backup/file.img
```

On the morning I found PC unresponsive (all writes were completed) - changing virtual terminal (Alt+F1, etc) didn't work. I've done a hard restart and couldn't get my PC to boot. Apparently, there was a timeout mounting /data. I've commented it out from fstab and booted successfully to the desktop. Then I found out that my original partition table was altered:

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sdb                                                                                           
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x55a7867a

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         128 3887231 3887104  1,9G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
```

I am currently creating a full disk image to the new separate HDD, and then I planning to perform data recovery.

SMART status looks healthy.

Any thoughts what could happen and how to try to recover data?

Comment: What was the command you used to copy that 200 GB file?

Comment: I mounted a directory from HDD on the remote machine using `sshfs` then i copied disk image:


`user@remote $ dd if=/dev/sda of=mounted_dir/file.img bs=4M status=progress conv=sync,noerror`

Comment: Did you hard restart using the power button or by using `REISUB`?

Comment: The system was completely unresponsive. I restart it by cutting power. Although the HDD LED was not blinking.

Comment: Based on the edit history, I see you added the command from your memory, not from the shell's history. An anticlimactic, but most likely explanation would be that you at some point accidentally to wrote to `sdb` instead of the mounted file-system on `sdb`. A mistake like this does not become apparent immediately as the mounted file-system information is likely to be cached in RAM.

Comment: Did you possibly swap tho `if` and the `of`?

Comment: I update the question. The dd command was run on the remote machine, which had access only to the mounted directory.

Comment: No idea, but `dd bs=4M conv=nosync,error`, if a read error is actually encountered, [it would likely result in a corrupt image](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171)

Comment: Possibly the image file, bud I don't think it's related to corrupting while filesystem on _remote_ machine.

Comment: It's impossible to tell how that happened from your question at all, hence "no idea". Just wanted to point out that the dd command might cause you grief further down the road, sucks to find out disk is bad and backup is also bad.

Comment: You could check syslogs if anything made it in there.

Comment: I can see an error with Nvidia driver, but there are no earlier logs. Approx couple of hours are missing.
https://pastebin.com/vDawxvd9

I can't find anything disk or filesystem related other than that.

Comment: @RARvolt There's also a `BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000000006d00` on line 108. What else was that machine running? Are you sure that the issue is due to the copying of your data?

Comment: @Kusalananda I never said that. It could be possibly unrelated. In that case guidance to where seek the problem would be appreciable. There was running a virtual machine if that may be related, but I was running it continuously for over half a year.